# how much should i charge to update website using shopify

Tags: web, shopify, designer, graphic

I am a graphic designer. i can design using photoshop, illustrator and know to work with html and css only.

Roughly how much should i charge to update website using shopify.

Can anybody advice me.?

Comment: I believe this question is off topic. Please Read through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: We can't really help you in this situation. Try to estimate how long the work will take you and how much per hour make it worth your while then add 10% for profit.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing what country or currecy you're using, I would suggest 5-10% lower than your competitors.

Comment: can u say in usd roughly? how much can i charge per month for shopify maintanence in updating.. because i have no idea..